# Asp.Net MVC Binding. Get List<Model> at controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, partial-views

I've got view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessRoute", "Calculator"))
    {

            @Html.TextBox("CityArrival", null, new { @style = "width: 300px;" })
            @Html.TextBox("CityDeparture", null, new { @style = "width: 300px;" })
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("BusModelList", @Model.BusModels);  }      
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Поиск" />
    }
```

partial view:

```
@model List<ViewModels.GroupedBusModelsSelectable>
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="left">@item.BusType.Name</td>
        </tr>
       foreach (var bus in item.BusModels.OrderBy(c => c.Bus.NumPlaces).ToList())
       {
            @Html.EditorFor(x=>bus);
       }
    }
</table>
```

and editor:

```
@model ViewModels.BusModelSelectable
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Bus.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Bus.FullName)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)
    </td>
    <td>
        <img>
    <td>
        @Model.Bus.FullName
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now I would like to get all busModels(with selected) at controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult ProcessRoute(string CityArrival, string CityDeparture, IEnumerable<GroupedBusModelsSelectable> BusModels)
```

By some reason BusModels is null

At HttpContext.Request.Form

I see list of (bus.IsSelected, bus.Bus.Id). How can I get it at controller?

**DECISION**

After Nick Larsen advice I understand that I should have indexed names at my html. Because I have two-level collection, I should do it  twice.

PartialView:

```
@model List<Avtobus66.ViewModels.GroupedBusModelsSelectable>
<table>
        @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Count(); j++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="left">@Model[j].BusType.Name</td>
            </tr>
            for (int i = 0; i < Model[j].BusModels.Count(); i++)
            {
               @Html.EditorFor(x => Model[j].BusModels[i]);
            }
        }
</table>
```

Let's see html now:

```
<input name="[0].BusModels[0].Bus.Id" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input name="[0].BusModels[0].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="[0].BusModels[0].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false" />

<input name="[0].BusModels[1].Bus.Id" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input name="[0].BusModels[1].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="[0].BusModels[1].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false" />

<input name="[0].BusModels[2].Bus.Id" type="hidden" value="3" />
<input name="[0].BusModels[2].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="[0].BusModels[2].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false" />

<input name="[1].BusModels[0].Bus.Id" type="hidden" value="4" />
<input name="[1].BusModels[0].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="[1].BusModels[0].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

At controller I'm ready get 2level collection now. At my case

```
IEnumerable<GroupedBusModelsSelectable> BusModels
```

it works. Now I'm agree with Nick, I should refactoring my table markup spaghetti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at what you are sending to the browser.  In order for the `BusModels` parameter to be populated, you need to send to the browser something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="BusModels[0].someProperty" value="whatever" />
<input type="hidden" name="BusModels[0].someOtherProperty" value="whatever" />
<input type="checkbox" name="BusModels[0].someBoolean" />

<input type="hidden" name="BusModels[1].someProperty" value="whatever" />
<input type="hidden" name="BusModels[1].someOtherProperty" value="whatever" />
<input type="checkbox" name="BusModels[1].someBoolean" />
```

Notice that the only thing that changed in the name is the value inside of the square brackets.  There are other ways to do this, but they are all variants on this method and you can find out more about them [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).  Since you list no controls to dynamically add new elements, I suggest the rewriting the editor as a template and using the built in functionality to build your inputs.

To achieve this, pass your model to the partial view already sorted, then instead of using a `foreach`, use a plain `for` loop and call an editor for indexes of your model.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessRoute", "Calculator"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("CityArrival", null, new { @style = "width: 300px;" })
    @Html.TextBox("CityDeparture", null, new { @style = "width: 300px;" })
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("BusModelList", Model.BusModels.OrderBy(c => c.Bus.NumPlaces).ToList());  }      
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Поиск" />
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model List<ViewModels.GroupedBusModelsSelectable>

<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="left">@item.BusType.Name</td>
    </tr>
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i]);
    }
}
</table>
```

That should do the trick.  The only thing other than this that I would mention is that you have split up the table and the rows of the table which creates a tight coupling between the view and the partial view.  A better way to handle this is to remove the coupling and put all related constructs in the same place.  The easiest and cleanest way to do this is to use a razor inline template, or move away from the table altogether because semantically editors are not tabular data.

Comment: Nick, thanks for the answer. I can achieve right binding. Now I would like fix my hard coupling code(table markup). What is the best practice??? No markups at editots, partials? But how can I "make it nice" at this way?

Comment: @AndrewKalashnikov: table rows can only be nested in a table, so all generation of `tr` elements should be in the same view (full or partial) as the `table` element they are nested under.  Currently you have `tr` elements generated in a separate view than the `table` which makes it fairly easy to generate table rows outside of a table.  Another reason is that the rows should be controlled by the same view that creates the table headers, and the list goes on and on.  You can achieve this same layout without using a table and avoid all of these problems.

Comment: thanks for showing the prefix to the index. Ala, BusModels[0].someProperty. Many examples only show the [0].someProperty part. With a form that has fields and lists being the norm, you showed me the correct way.